# How do I show all calendar events in "Today view" in iOS 9?

Tags: iphone, calendar, ios

I just updated my iPhone to iOS 9 and noticed my "Today View" only lists my next calendar event vs all my calendar events for the day.

**Is there a way to change this so it shows all calendar events for the day?**

I frequently use this to quickly see what's scheduled for my day and plan ahead for meetings, breaks, etc. later in the day. I cannot find anything in Settings > Notifications, or on the Edit menu on the Today View.

<sup>Add'd info: My iPhone is a 5s and I updated from iOS 7, skipping iOS 8, so I'm not sure if this change was in iOS 8 since I skipped it.</sup>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if by "*Today's View*" you actually mean the iOS 9 "*Todays View"* or the Calendar Widget. To activate the Calendar Widget scroll to the end of your Notification Center and touch "Edit" and add the Calendar Widget.

Now, regarding how the info of your next appointments on the Calendar Widget will look like, it depends on how you present them on the actual Calendar App.

As you can see in the pictures bellow, on the left you have a **relative** presentation of the events and on the right an **absolute** presentation.

I hope this clarifies things a bit.

[image: Calendar Widget]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation - this fixes my issue and I'm thrilled!