# iPad iOS 9 Today View - Calendar Listing

Tags: ipad, notifications, bug, ios

How do you list your day's appointments on your iPad "Today's View"

The article for the link below was great iPhone but not so much for iPad.

[How do I show all calendar events in "Today view" in iOS 9?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/206921/how-do-i-show-all-calendar-events-in-today-view-in-ios-9)

Thanks,
Al

Answer (score 1):

If you swipe to the bottom of the today screen you should see the edit button. If you tap that you should see the option to place the calendar in the 'Today' section (see below)

[image: Edit]

In the pull down menu, I now have two sections: the 'Today View' and 'Widgets View'.  The Today View shows me the current temperature, below that the next appointment on my calendar.  **Below that** it shows me the appointments in my calendar for the *whole day*.

Comment: I can see the edit button and add calendar to Today View, but it only lists one appointment. The next one in my day. On the iPhone all appointments can be listed and seen.

Comment: @Alsy27 I assume then that you have more than one appointment?

Comment: N_Soong yes I have more than one event / appointment. Thanks I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Alsy27 I've edited the answer now; if that doesn't solve your problem, there might be a bug.  With that setup for the Today View though you should definitely have the whole day's worth of events/appointments.

Comment: Thank you. Perplexing for sure. Must be a bug. Still an issue for me on the iPad. Not the iPhone.